# showing a function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

While working on analysis continuity, i came across this question.I have understood the concept of continuity but cant see how to answer this question by including epsilon delta.

$$f(x) =\begin{cases} x,&  x\in \mathbb Q \\
 x^2,& x\in \mathbb {R\setminus Q}
\end{cases}$$

Show that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ and $x=1$, but discontinuous at all other points.

Comment: Hint: it's probably easier to prove this using the theorem that "$f$ is continuous at $x \iff $ for all sequences $(x_n)$ with $x_n \rightarrow x$, $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$."

Comment: sequentially continuous can be used for x=0 and x=1 but how do i prove for discontinuous at all other points

Comment: If $x$ is rational, take a sequence of irrational points that tends to $x$; and vice versa.